# Assigning attribute of Get-ADUser to a variable without headers

Tags: powershell, active-directory, formatting, filtering

Here is my code:

```
$var = Get-ADUser -Identity username | Select -Property ObjectGUID

Echo $var
```

My output is :

```
ObjectGUID    
-------------
XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I dont want the headers in the variable, so i can pass it to commands with ease.

Please send help and caffiene.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$var = Get-ADUser -Identity username | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ObjectGUID
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the default output with the actual contents of your variable.  `$var` contains an *object* which has a *property* called `ObjectGUID`.  The default output is just showing you this.

To see only the value of `ObjectGUID`, simply type (`echo`, or its underlying command `Write-Output`, is typically not needed):

```
$var.ObjectGUID
```

To use it as input to another cmdlet, you can do things like:

```
$var.ObjectGUID | My-Command
```

or

```
My-Command -Guid $var.ObjectGUID
```